# How to switch view controllers in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to switch from one UIViewController to another using code. Right now I have,

```
self.presentViewController(ResultViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

All this is doing is taking me to a black screen instead of the ResultViewController. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 24):

With Storyboard. Create a swift file (SecondViewController.swift) for the second view controller
and in the appropriate function type this:

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! secondViewController

self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Without storyboard

```
let secondViewController = ViewController(nibNameOrNil: NibName, bundleOrNil: nil)
self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I don't want it to start a new intent activity; I just need it to literally switch the views, because I have an intro text in the beginning which never ever needs to be displayed again, and I don't want them able to "back" to it. So it needs to be permanently replaced by the table view.

Comment: What is `NibName`?

Answer (score 8):

You can try this one

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ResultView") as ResultViewController

self.presentViewController(resultViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Make sure you set your view controller identifier.

[image]

Comment: I don't want it to start a new intent activity; I just need it to literally switch the views, because I have an intro text in the beginning which never ever needs to be displayed again, and I don't want them able to "back" to it. So it needs to be permanently replaced by the table view.

Comment: What if you want the ResultView to reload as part of the switch to it?

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3**

To present a controller modally

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateWithIdentifier("SecondViewController")
self.present(vc, animate: true, completion: nil)
```

To show a controller

```
self.show(vc, sender: self)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let vc = ViewController(nibNameOrNil: yourNibName, bundleOrNil: nil)
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: You should add some sort of explanation as to why this solves the problem. Also, what if OP is using storyboards?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be to create a segue by right clicking on the view you are starting on and dragging the blue line to the result view controller the hit the show segue option. Then set the identifier of the segue to "segue". Now add this code wherever you would like in your view controller:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
```

this will trigger the segue that will go to your resultViewController

Answer (score 1):

vc = YourViewController()

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc

Or

vc = YourViewController()

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc) //If you want to add navigation functionality to that VC

Comment: It might be obvious to you but can you elaborate?

Comment: vc = YourViewCotroller() //the VC you want to navigate to

Comment: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow //here you are telling the compiler that you want to handle the root/main window by code then you will type .rootViewController // means the ViewController That you to make As the startUp/Destination ViewController

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to switch between screens in iOS is. Add a button on the current screen. Then press control and drag the button to the target screen. Then select push. And when you will tap the button the screen will be switched to the target screen. 
Make sure you are using a UINavigationViewController.

Source: [ios UINavigationController Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedios.net/ios-uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

Shaba's answer is a good start but requires the following so that you
can control the segue from within your view controller:

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, 
              sender: Any?) -> Bool {    
 // your code here    
 // return true to execute the segue    
 // return false to cause the segue to gracefully fail  }
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621502-shouldperformsegue)