# Presenting the new controller programatically in ios swift only displaying blank screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am developing a simple IOS application using swift. In my application I need to open new controller programatically from another controller. So I added another scene to the storyboard.

This is the screenshot
[image]

Then I added a new class for new controller which is inheriting from the UIViewController. This is the code for new controller

```
import UIKit

class ReplayController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Then, I tried to open the new controller view (ReplayController) from the main controller like this in code.

```
func gameOver()
    {
        let replayController = ReplayController()
        present(replayController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

When I call that function, it just pops up the blank screen. Nothing appear on the screen. What is wrong and how can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instantiate and Present a viewController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: `ReplayController()` That's creating a New object. But not a `ReplayController` object initialized with the UI part in the Storyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch view controllers in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375409/how-to-switch-view-controllers-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Storyboard file, ensure the `ReplayController` has its 'File's Owner' set to your `ReplayController` class.  Then set the Storyboard ID like below:

[image]

Then you can load it like so:

```
let replay = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReplayController") as! ReplayController
self.present(replay, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: There is no storybord id filed. I could only find RestorationID

Answer (score 2):

You have to reference it with id in storyboard

```
 let replayController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "replayControllerID") as! ReplayController

 present(replayController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

as this line only

```
let replayController = ReplayController()
```

doesn't load the xib or storyboard object associated with the VC

Answer (score 1):

When you design your view controllers in storyboard, you need to programatically create them using the method `instantiateViewController` of  class `UIStoryboard` to access it along with all the outlets.

Before that, you need to set the **Storyboard ID** of the respective view controller in your storyboard like this:

[image: Storyboard ID Screenshot]

And then present it:

```
func gameOver() {
    if let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") {
        self.present(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```